# OpenGL filled polygon color "bleeding"

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to draw a 5 pointed star shape in openGL (Java) that is both filled and outlined. The code i'm using to draw it

```
gl.glPushAttrib(GL.GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);
try {
   // set attributes for filling the shape
   Color fillColor = Color.GREEN;
   float[] rgb = fill.getRGBColorComponents(null);
   gl.glColor4f(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], 1f);
   gl.glEnable(GL.GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
   gl.glPolygonMode(GL.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL.GL_FILL);                    
   gl.glEnable(GL.GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
   gl.glCallList(this.glListId);

   // set attributes for outlining the shape
   gl.glEnable(GL.GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
   Color outline = Color.RED;
   float[] rgb = outline.getRGBColorComponents(null);
   gl.glColor4f(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], 1f);
   gl.glPolygonMode(GL.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL.GL_LINE);
   gl.glLineWidth(5);                 
   gl.glCallList(this.glListId);
}
finally {
    gl.glPopAttrib();
}
```

The creation of the call list just looks like:

```
gl.glNewList(this.glListId, GL.GL_COMPILE);
gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POLYGON);
for (int j = 0; j < xCoords.length; j++) {
   // 2d polygon
   gl.glVertex2d(xCoords[j], yCoords[j]);
}
gl.glEnd();
```

When I do this, the outline of the star draws perfectly, but the fill color bleeds outside the edges of the outline (if I draw it without the outline, the polygon looks does not look crisp either). Any ideas why?

EDIT: I added a screenshot showing the problem

[image]

thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Have you tried using a simple `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`?

Comment: Would I be able to do the outline with the triangle fans also? I'm thinking that if I do that then the outline would show all of the inner triangles...

Comment: @Jeff: No you can do the outline with a single GL_LINE_STRIP and ignore the first vertex for that call. The GL_TRIANGLE_FAN needs an extra vertex for the center. You don't have to do everything in the same GL type, because there will still be two forloops for openGL to draw.

Comment: Um, same problem here. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "star shape", remember that [`GL_POLYGON`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBegin.xml) can only render convex polygons correctly:

> `GL_POLYGON`:
>
> Draws a single, convex polygon. 
>   Vertices 1 through N define this
>   polygon.

Comment: I am using the same display list for both the outline and the fill, so why would one look good but the other not?

Comment: The outline just draws the line segments in order, so it doesn't care what is "inside" or "outside" the polygon. The fill algorithm does need to know, and that determination is much easier if the polygon is convex, so most fill algorithms require it. You can always break up your concave polygon into multiple convex polygons if you need to.

Comment: I see. So I would need to draw the fill outline with one shape, and fill with the other set? This way only the outside of the star would be outlined (and not all of the inner triangles), correct?